# Youtube Api retrieving data very slowly for some keywords

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am using youtube api data for retrieving  youtube data using the below url link

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=hello&key=apikey&v=2&alt=json

when i search for some specific keywords like 'songs hd'  it is taking too much time to retrieve data, instead it takes less time to retrieve data when i search 'songs hd' in the youtube website..

Can any one tell me how to retrieve the youtube data very fastly

Comment: Really? i tried song%20hd and the speed quite normal(less than 1 seconds).

Comment: It may be a temporary problem.

Comment: when i am loading the above youtube api data after clicking a button, it takes too much time to retrieve the data, please tell me how to load the youtube api data fastly in my site